# Get Access to Mockall Mocks that are used by the tested code inside of an Arc

Tags: rust, mockall

I am trying to test code in rust using Mocks from the mockall crate.

```rust
    #[automock]
    trait MyTrait {
        fn some_func(&self) -> i64;
    }
    
    
    struct MyStruct {
        data: Arc<dyn MyTrait>
    }
    
    impl MyStruct {
    
        // ... lots of code
    }
    
    #[test]
    fn a_test() {
        let mut mock = MockMyTrait::new();
        mock.expect_some_func().return_const(42);
        let testee = MyStruct { data: Arc::new(mock) };
    
        // test a lot of code from MyStruct
    
        // here I want to call 'mock.chekcpoint()' and setup more expectations
    
        // test some more MyStruct code
    }
```

Since the mock is now moved into the `Arc` I do not know how I can access the `checkpoint` method of the mock object. Is there a way to get access to the Mock object or is there a better way for me to structure my code to make testing easier/possible ?

Comment: You can share ownership between your test and `MyStruct` (since you are already using `Arc`), but you won't be able to get exclusive access to *mutate* the `mock` (in order to checkpoint or add expectations) while `MyStruct` has a handle to it.

Comment: I think that wont work, since the Arc uses type <dyn MyTrait> so I can only share access to the  Trait object and not to the underlying Mock object as far as I know. If the Arc would not use a "dyn" reference I could "unsafe" get a mut reference. That would not be very nice but itr would work. I do not know if that works with Trait Objects

Comment: @ptriller This is not true. You can have one copy of an `Arc` as `Arc<dyn Trait>` and another as `Arc<ConcreteType>`. However `checkpoint()` takes `&mut self`.

Comment: Unsafe is not the solution. It'll either be unsound, or can be accomplished with safe code.

Comment: Are you able to destroy your struct and recreate it after editing the mock? That'd probably be the only way. (Or swap out `data` with a dummy value and swap the mock back in after editing, but that assumes your struct doesn't utilize the shared ownership of `Arc` itself).